# hyperlink to an existing Outlook mail message

Tags: vba, hyperlink, outlook

In Outlook 2016, I'd like the body of a mail message to include a hyperlink to another, existing mail message.

The general idea is that message2 would have a link to message1, and anyone who's previously received message1 and is reading message2 could click the link to open their own copy of message1 (i.e., in their own Outlook inbox; no cross-mailbox permissions needed; link would only try to access the clicker's own inbox).

I know that setting the href to "outlook:ENTRYID" is a possibility. (Without the quotes, and of course substituting actual entryID for that placeholder.) But the value of ENTRYID changes when the message is moved to a different folder, and anyway is unique to "my" mailbox (and wouldn't work for recipients of message2).

And I've learned how to get the PR_SEARCH_KEY of an existing email (thanks to [this article](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-mapi-properties-exposed-outlooks-object-model/)).

But an href of "outlook:PR_SEARCH_KEY" doesn't work / target can't be found.

Finally, I've read that "outlook:GUID" works. But I can't figure out how (in Outlook VBA) to get the GUID of an existing email.

Does anyone know how to programmatically (VBA) get the GUID? Or convert PR_SEARCH_KEY to be a GUID? Or (back to my root question) any other way to create a hyperlink to an existing Outlook mail message?

The hyperlink only needs to work from within Outlook 2016 itself (so no concerns about the "outlook:" protocol not being recognized elsewhere on my computer).

Thanks very much.

Comment: How are message1 and message2 related? Part of the same conversation?

Comment: Not necessarily the same conversation. More like I sent an email a couple weeks ago, and now (separate conversation) a question has come up that I discussed in detail back then. So I'd like today's email (message2) to have a hyperlink (or anything easy for the recipient to click) that opens the old email -- assuming of course that message1 is still in their mailbox and they haven't deleted it. Of course I can always say "please find that email I sent" and give them subject/date/etc location info. But it'd be much nicer to say "please click here to see details from two weeks ago". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other unique ID; PR_ENTRYID and PR_SEARCH_KEY are the only ones.  However, you can use the email subject.  See the following KB article:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/158135/ol97-using-hyperlinks-to-access-outlook-folders-and-items.  Also see: [Using Outlook Links](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/using-outlook-links/).

Comment: Thanks. I saw that article, but thought it meant i need to know which folder the other user filed message1 in, right? (hopefully I'm wrong in that, esp with multiple recipients & possible folder locations.) Also, though, subject line  won't get me to one specific email out of a larger chain, right? 

Any way to make a url out of PR_SEARCH_KEY? 

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need to know the folder location. No, you can't use PR_SEARCH_KEY. My 2 cents: Outlook message hyperlinks are not reliable - don't use them.